# How to play an audio file (.mp3) in a cell when a button is clicked in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, excel-2016

In Microsoft Excel, How do I play an audio file (`.mp3`) that is embedded in a cell when a button is clicked. I want it to **play in Excel without opening any media player** like Media Player Classic or Windows Media Player etc.

**Note:** There are several audio files and I added buttons next to each audio file. So It can play one audio file using one button.

What I tried is, I created a **Macro Button**, and I added this code,

```
Sub Start_Audio()

y = Range("F5").Value         
x = ActiveCell.Value          

Shell ("C:\Program Files\MPC-HC.1.6.6.6957.x64\mpc-hc64.exe /startpos " + x + " " + y)
End Sub
```

But that code gives me an error.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @BruceWayne It opens Media Player Classic and gives an error. What I want is to  play audio in excel without opening any player.

Comment: Check [this page](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/playing_sound_from_excel/), does that help?  Or the late, great [Chip Pearson's page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/PlaySound.aspx)?

Comment: @BruceWayne I embedded all mp3s to excel sheet. So I can give cell name as the audio path. So can you give me the solution here 

WAVFile = "dogbark.wav"
WAVFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & WAVFile
Call PlaySound(WAVFile, 0&, SND_ASYNC Or SND_FILENAME)